# how to reuse custom form validation rules in other forms in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, dry

I have the following custom validation for a combination of fields I use throughout my site:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_field_type_constant = 'my_field_type'
    my_field_code_constant = 'my_field_code'

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def validate_my_field_code(self, my_field_code_error, my_field_type, my_field_code):

        validate = URLValidator(verify_exists=False)
        try:
            validate(my_field_code)
        except ValidationError:
            messsge = u"My custom error"
            self._errors[my_field_code_error] = self.error_class([messsge])


    def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super(MyModelForm, self).clean()
        my_field_type = cleaned_data.get(self.my_field_type_constant)
        my_field_code = cleaned_data.get(self.my_field_code_constant)

        my_field_type_from_model = other_model.models.my_field_TYPES[1][0]
        if my_field_type == my_field_type_from_model:
            self.validate_my_field_code(self.my_field_code_constant, my_field_type, my_field_code)
        return cleaned_data
```

I use the combination of my_field_type and my_field_code in many of the forms in my site.  I want to adhere to the DRY principle.  How do I make the validation for these fields available to other forms without copying and pasting it into all the other forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just subclass your other ModelForm classes that will use this validation:

```
class MyOtherModelForm(MyModelForm):
    pass
```

Then you get it all for free though inheritance.